# Grails date conversion from and to Mongo

Tags: mongodb, grails

I am using the Grails MongoDb plugin and trying to get the Date conversion.

In my config I have defined different dateFormats

```
grails.databinding.dateFormats = [ 
    'yyyy-MM-dd', 
    'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S', 
    "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'" 
]
```

However when I read a record from mongodb into my Customer domain class, I still get this error: What am I doing wrong?

> org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert
>   property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type
>   'java.util.Date' for property 'lastUpdateDate'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to
>   convert from type java.lang.String to type
>   @org.grails.databinding.BindingFormat java.util.Date for value
>   '1994-01-29T00:00:00Z'; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.NumberFormatException:
>   For input string: "1994-01-29T00:00:00Z"

Comment: what are you reading from your db? Is the date saved as a string or as a date?

Comment: Yes I am reading from DB as a string date. The pseudo code I used was:

    def cust = new Customer (lasUpdateDate: new Date())
    def obj  = (DBObject) com.mongodb.util.JSON.parse ("${cust as JSON}")
    mongo.customers.insert (cust)

Which is basically what I would expect Grails to do underneath.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have manually inserted the value of `lastUpdateDate` in your MongoDB database which got stored in `String` format instead of MongoDB's `ISODate()` format. Delete or modify that record in database and this will work fine.

Comment: Yes. Those recrods were created using gmongo directly because I was running out of memory using Grails alone in long batch mode. I thought Grails would use the binding date format when loading objects from bson but I guess it doesn't which is a shame. What surprises me is that if you transform an object in JSON you get a date string. so why not be able to read it back.